# order random with limit loop for ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, for-loop

I have this loop:

```
<% for post in posts.order_by([:created_at, :desc]).limit(6) %>
  post.name
<% end %>
```

This works fine, but I want now get the name for each post, with random order and limit 6.

I would like how works with for and each block like:

```
posts.each do |post|
 post.name
end
```

Comment: What are you asking?  How to randomize the order?  Also are you trying to print this out or get it into an Array or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
posts.limit(6).shuffle.each do |post|
  post.name
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely certain what you're asking but it sounds to me like you could do something like this:

```
<% posts.limit(6).shuffle.each do |post| %>
  <%= post.name %>
  <br>
<% end %>
```

[See the docs for the Array class's shuffle method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-shuffle) for more details on usage for randomization.